# Alerts based on message data in Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a usecase where I have to send alerts to users based on data in Kafka topic. I have one topic which carries iot data from various iot devices. I have to send notifications to users if an iot device has stopped working. What is the best possible way to do this using KSQL ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would need more info to comment.

Comment: Do you know the full list of devices?  e.g. is there another key-compacted topic somewhere (or db table that could be dumped to a topic), that stores the ids of all know devices?

Or must we infer the list of devices from the events in the Kafka topic?

Comment: What would indicate a device has stopped working? I'm assuming if it doesn't send an update for a certain amount of time?